# Javascript ajax post textbox text to ActionResult asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post

**Html**

```
<input type="password" id="LoginPasswordText" title="Password" style="width: 150px" />


<input type="button" id="LoginButton1" value="Save" class="LoginButton1Class" onclick="LoginButton1OnClick" />
```

**Json**

```
var TextBoxData = {
Text: LoginPasswordText.GetValue(),
};


   function LoginButton1OnClick() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/MyActionResult",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(TextBoxData),

            success: function (mydata) {
               alert("Success");
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
```

**MyActionResult**

```
public ActionResult MyActionResult(string Text)
{
 return view();
}
```

**Above codes(Html,Json,MyActionResult) works very well but it is json data.**

**I want to send above codes as ajax data.And i tried below code.
However below code does not work , if i click to button , i can not send any data and there is nothing.Where i miss ?**

```
<script>
    function LoginButton1OnClick() {

         var TextBoxData = {
    Text: LoginPasswordText.GetValue(),
    };


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Home/MyActionResult",
            data: TextBoxData,
            success: function () {
                alert('success');
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to wrap in an additional object. Also you have invalid javascript. There's a trailing comma after the `LoginPasswordText.GetValue()` call resulting in a javascript error. Also in order to retrieve the value of the input field you could use the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function.

So simply send the value as-is:

```
<script>
    function LoginButton1OnClick() {
        var text = $('#LoginPasswordText').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Home/MyActionResult",
            data: text,
            success: function () {
                alert('success');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

This will send the string value to the following controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyActionResult(string text)
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: hi, i get exception " Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'GetValue' "

Comment: data:

                {
                    text: $("#LoginPasswordText").val()
                }, solved problem

Comment: That's because such method doesn't exist in jQuery. I thought that it was some custom function you have written but apparently I am mistaken. See my updated answer.