# razor mvc4 how to insert jquery function into sql database

Tags: jquery, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

how to i get the slider value into the database?

i have tried passing in id but it doesn't work, anybody can help? Thanks!

```
<script>
$( function ()
{
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider( {
        orientation: "vertical",
        range: true,
        values: [17, 67],
        slide: function ( event, ui )
        {
            $( "#amount" ).val(  + ui.values[0] + "by" + ui.values[1] );
        }
    } );
    $( "#amount" ).val( "" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
    " by " + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
} );
```

```
<input type="text" id="amount" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.PuzzleDimension, new { id = "amount" } )  
</p>
```

Comment: Do want to store the slider value into DB on slider change or on click of some button like save? You can use ajax post based on the requirement i.e. onTextChanged or onClick of the button.

Comment: yes the store value i had the click button but it doesnt store inside

Comment: Please refer link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21259290/javascript-ajax-post-textbox-text-to-actionresult-asp-net-mvc for details how to post the textbox value to controller method on click of button.